# How to skip null entries with Gson

Tags: android, json, gson

When deserializing JSON with Gson, is there a way to skip null entries in a JSON array?

```
[
    {
        text: "adsfsd...",
        title: "asdfsd..."
    },
    null,
    {
        text: "adsfsd...",
        title: "asdfsd..."
    }
]
```

The resulting List has 3 entries and the second one is null. I would like to configure Gson to skip the nulls but I could not find a way to do it.

Comment: It should handle automatically. What is the error

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude null values by writing your own custom gson JsonDeserializer

Assuming that you have your model class

```
 class GetData {
    private String title;
    private String text;
}

class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<GetData>> {

    @Override
    public List<GetData> deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

       JsonArray jsonArray =    jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();

       List<GetData>  list=new ArrayList<>(30);
       Gson gson = new Gson();

       for (JsonElement element : jsonArray) {
           // skipping the null here, if not null then parse json element and add in collection
           if(!(element instanceof JsonNull))
           {
               list.add(gson.fromJson(element,  GetData.class));
           }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Finally you can parse it

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Collection.class, new CustomDeserializer()).create();
gson.fromJson(builder.toString(), Collection.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, a custom deserializer is probably what I need, but I was hoping for something easier, like serializeNulls() for serialization, so I will wait a little longer before accepting.

Comment: Yup, sure would be a lot nicer if there was an easier way exclude null elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way :(

Answer (score 0):

Null values are excluded by default as long as you don't set `serializeNulls()` to your GsonBuilder. Once I found this. and worked for me:

```
class CollectionAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Collection<?>> {
  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(Collection<?> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    if (src == null || src.isEmpty()) // exclusion is made here
      return null;

    JsonArray array = new JsonArray();

    for (Object child : src) {
      JsonElement element = context.serialize(child);
      array.add(element);
    }

    return array;
  }
}
```

Then register this by this code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Collection.class, new CollectionAdapter()).create();
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a solution for deserializing. serializeNulls() only impacts serialization. Also your custom serializer does not help here.